# Selenium - Abrir Chrome com extenções já instaladas

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extensão

Galera, preciso que a instancia do Chrome aberta via WebDriver venha com um plugin ja instalado "Sempre" que eu abrir.

Achei alguns conteudos, porém não funciona aqui.
Sabem dizer se foi por conta da atualização do SeleniumDriver?

Segue o código:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class Testes {
    @Test
    public void testeNavegador() {
        try {
            WebDriver navegador = null;
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.addExtensions(new File("C:\\Office-Editor_v130.54.56.crx"));
            DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            desiredCapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY,chromeOptions);
            navegador = new ChromeDriver(desiredCapabilities);
            navegador.get("chrome://extensions/");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Alguma solução?

Answer (score -1):

Aqui você encontra muito bem explicado como fazer...
https://seleniumjava.com/2016/05/22/start-the-chrome-browser-with-extensions/

A única coisa que ficou meio confuso, foi que ele diz que após instalar as extensões, você deve fechar o navegador e quando abrir pelo selenium as extensões deveriam estar ativas...

Descobri que não vem ativadas. O que deve fazer após todo o procedimento, é abrir o navegador através do selenium e então instalar as extensões. E toda vez que for abrir pelo selenium novamente, as extensões estarão lá...

Espero ter ajudado ao menos os próximos visitantes desta pergunta...